# Is String Theory the end of (currently known) physics?

Tags: string-theory, theory-of-everything, unified-theories

Assuming that String Theory were true, does it explain all the currently known physics? Or are there anything that is known to exist and that even String Theory would not be able to explain?

Comment: String theories have the possibility to model all four known interactions, strong, weak, electromagnetic, gravitational, but there are thousands of them and no definite proposal up for validation by experiments has been  thought up yet. As the answer states there are many open fields in physics  and one does not even know if once a string theory model is  proposed if some falsification by experiments will not open new avenues for physics, as it has been happening since Newtons time.

Comment: With string theory, I'm reminded of the remark Alfoso X is said to have made about the Ptolemaic model of the heavens: *"If the Lord Almighty had consulted me before embarking on creation thus, I should have recommended something simpler."*

Comment: I'm voting to close as primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit too broad and too loosely defined to be tackled properly. What do you mean by the *end* of currently known physics ? Do you mean end as in "complete knowledge" ? Do you mean end as in "no more experiments to run" ? Or perhaps you mean end as in "we have a way of explaining everything" ?

The short answer to all three is

### No

As I understand it, string theory is a subset of M-theory but the phrase has grown to become a sort of umbrella term for mathematical models/mathematical theories of marrying quantum mechanics with gravity.

And unless I'm mistaken, the predictions from string theory are often multitudinous and non-unique, leading many physicists to consider the theory not fully developed. Yet.

But even if string theory turned out to be as correct as possible, there's still **lots** of physics that are open-ended questions, *hundreds* of them, theoretical or otherwise. We don't even have a 100% complete understanding of friction ! There's so many unexplained phenomena in astrophysics, condensed matter physics, nuclear physics, biophysics, etc.

Cosmological inflation is still hotly debated, the mechanism of metallic whiskering is still unknown, space roar is still mysterious and those are just a few off the top of my head. The job is far from done !